# Angular2 / Typescript - Error pushing element

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my function:

```
foo(o) {
    let olditems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
    let newitem = {'obj': o};
    olditems.push(newitem);
    console.log(olditems);
}
```

I want to push the object `o` to my `localStorage`.

It gives me an error:

```
error_handler.js:46 EXCEPTION: Error in ... - inline template:7:65 caused by: olditems.push is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method .push is not available for objects, if you want to add something to an object you just have to create the property in the object.

```
olditem.obj = o;
```

or

```
olditem['obj'] = o;
```

And then set the item in you localStorage